# How do you set initial focus in a layout?

Tags: rebol, rebol3, r3-gui

```
rebol []

view [ 
    f: field "" 
    button "focus" on-action [
        focus f
    ]
    when [load] on-action [focus f] 
]
```

Using the `focus` button sets the focus correctly but I'd like the focus to set when the panel appears.  I'd have thought the `load` trigger should do this but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct trigger to use is the 'enter trigger

```
when [enter] on-action [focus f]
```